# expansion universe and proper length

Tags: general-relativity, space-expansion

Experimentally, the universe keeps expanding. I do not understand well what is meant by expanding universe.

If we assume an inertial reference frame for which space is defined and if in this reference frame we define a proper length as the distance between 2 atoms in the $O_2$ molecule(both atoms belong to the same inertial reference frame). My question is :

**Since the universe is expanding, is that distance going to increase with universe expansion or could that distance be used to measure that universe has indeed expanded?**

I feel there is some picture that I have got wrong.

Comment: Are you asking whether the $O_2$ bond length increases as the universe expands? If so see [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/why-does-space-expansion-not-expand-matter)

Comment: Well, you have the scale wrong,  (or I have your question wrong,sorry), that particular measuring device is far too short to measure expansion of space. The electrostatic attraction is much greater than any stretch of space will overcome,

Comment: @countt010 that was a mind experience not a realistic one but we could have taken the measuring system earth-moon whose relative motions are slow enough to consider them as belonging to the same inertial frame. However, they experience acceleration which means they are not inertial frame...